# Usage of activation function in node classification with GraphNets

Tags: python, graph, deep-learning, activation-function, graph-neural-network

I am currently trying to learn how Graph Neural Networks work with Deep Minds Graph-Nets-Library, but I am stuck for days with my understanding of this topic. Maybe someone of you can help me out.

I am using Zacharys Karate Club as graph dataset, where it is the goal to perform a node classification to determine which node (person) is loyal to which instructor ( Node 0 or Node 33).

For this purpose I am using the InteractionNetwork module with Linear modules for the node and edge updates. I did assume (and maybe this is where I misunderstood something about Deep Learning) that if I put a sigmoid activation function after the node update, the nodes would have either 0 (loyal to Node 0) or 1 (loyal to Node 1) as values. But I get different double values.

Below is the code that I am using:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tree
from pyvis.network import Network
from graph_nets import blocks
from graph_nets import graphs
from graph_nets import modules
from graph_nets import utils_np
from graph_nets import utils_tf

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import sonnet as snt
import tensorflow as tf
import functools

# making GraphsTuple from karate club dataset
# get dataset from nx
karate_graph = nx.karate_club_graph()
karate_graph_tupel = karate_graph

# getting node informations
# labeling the nodes
nodes = []
for i in range(1,34):
    if i == 1:
        nodes.append(0)
    if i == 33:
        nodes.append(1)
    else:
        nodes.append(-1)
nodes = np.reshape(nodes, (len(nodes), 1))
nodes_float = tf.cast(nodes, dtype=tf.float64)

# getting edge informations
# make graph undirected
directed_edges = karate_graph.edges
undirected_edges = [(u, v) for u, v in directed_edges] + [(v, u) for u, v in directed_edges]

karate_graph.edges = undirected_edges

edges = [[0.0] for _ in range(karate_graph.number_of_edges()*2)]

# getting sender and receiver informations
sender = []
receiver = []
for tupel in karate_graph.edges:
     sender.append(tupel[0])
     receiver.append(tupel[1])


# create GraphTuple from received informations
data_dict = {
    "nodes": nodes_float,
    "edges": edges,
    "senders": sender,
    "receivers": receiver
}

graphs_tuple = utils_np.data_dicts_to_graphs_tuple([data_dict])
graphs_tuple = tree.map_structure(lambda x: tf.constant(x) if x is not None else None, graphs_tuple)




# defining graph network
graph_network = modules.InteractionNetwork(
    node_model_fn=lambda: snt.Sequential([snt.Linear(output_size=1), tf.nn.sigmoid]),
    edge_model_fn=lambda: snt.Sequential([snt.Linear(output_size=1)])
)

# optimizer and loss function
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

# learning loop
for epoch in range(50):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

        output_graph = graph_network(graphs_tuple)

        # Loss for labeled nodes
        labeled_nodes = [0, 33]
        labeled_indices = [i for i in labeled_nodes if graphs_tuple.nodes[i] != -1]
        loss = loss_fn(tf.gather(graphs_tuple.nodes, labeled_indices), tf.gather(output_graph.nodes, labeled_indices))

    # calculate gradient
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, graph_network.trainable_variables)

    # apply gradient
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, graph_network.trainable_variables))

    # Loss output
    print("Epoch %d | Loss: %.4f" % (epoch, loss.numpy()))

print(output_graph.nodes)
print(output_graph.edges)
```

This is the output that I get:

Loss-funtion:

```
> Epoch 0 | Loss: 0.6619
Epoch 1 | Loss: 0.6547
Epoch 2 | Loss: 0.6478
Epoch 3 | Loss: 0.6412
Epoch 4 | Loss: 0.6351
Epoch 5 | Loss: 0.6292
Epoch 6 | Loss: 0.6233
Epoch 7 | Loss: 0.6172
Epoch 8 | Loss: 0.6110
Epoch 9 | Loss: 0.6048
Epoch 10 | Loss: 0.5988
Epoch 11 | Loss: 0.5931
Epoch 12 | Loss: 0.5877
Epoch 13 | Loss: 0.5826
Epoch 14 | Loss: 0.5777
Epoch 15 | Loss: 0.5728
Epoch 16 | Loss: 0.5680
Epoch 17 | Loss: 0.5633
Epoch 18 | Loss: 0.5589
Epoch 19 | Loss: 0.5549<
```

Nodes:

```
> [[0.09280719]
 [0.04476126]
 [0.03025987]
 [0.13695013]
 [0.34953291]
 [0.26353402]
 [0.26353402]
 [0.26353402]
 [0.22878334]
 [0.47378198]
 [0.34953291]
 [0.54787342]
 [0.44657832]
 [0.22878334]
 [0.47378198]
 [0.47378198]
 [0.41969087]
 [0.44657832]
 [0.47378198]
 [0.40082739]
 [0.47378198]
 [0.44657832]
 [0.47378198]
 [0.21003225]
 [0.32505647]
 [0.32505647]
 [0.47378198]
 [0.28533633]
 [0.37482885]
 [0.28533633]
 [0.28533633]
 [0.16495933]
 [0.01520448]
 [0.83080503]], shape=(34, 1), dtype=float64)<
```

I did not mention the edges, because I dont think that they are relevant for this issue and it would be too much information.

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately it's not possible to run your code; I get this error `InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__ConcatV2_N_3_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} ConcatOp : Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal: shape[0] = [156,1] vs. shape[1] = [78,1] [Op:ConcatV2] name: concat`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I changed to code a little bit before posting to make it better readable and didn't pay attention that the edges should be defined before the senders and receivers. The edited code should work now. Actually I already figured out that the problem was that I assumed that the sigmoid function acts like a step function. The values that I get do actually range from 0 to 1 like they should.

Comment: But I do actually struggle with another problem and maybe you can help with it: The nodes were unlabeled beginning still get a value of -1 and this affects all nodes, because their message is also passed among them. Is there a way to assign to these nodes an empty value?